# Why Entity Framework doesn't map a Oracle view with Union operator?

Tags: entity-framework, oracle11g, union

With Entity Framework i can map differents views from Oracle, for example a view with many **SELECTS** in different tables, **SUBQUERIES** and **CASES**, but when the view contains a **UNION**, EF doesn't map the view.

I want to know why is this happenning, because there isn't information about this topic.

Comment: I can't imagine EF inspects the view definition when mapping it. Are you sure it's only the `UNION` and not something else, like unsupported data types?

Comment: Im sure @GertArnold , with a `UNION` EF doesn't map the view, i have an example:

`CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VIEW_EXAMPLE AS

SELECT COURIER FROM COURIER

UNION

SELECT FAMILY from FAMILY;`. When i call this view in my edmx file, he  doesn't load the view.

Comment: I think the UNION causes EF to infer all columns as nullable. Could you try something like [this](http://girlfromoutofthisworld.com/entity-framework-and-setting-primary-keys-on-views/)?

Comment: Other question: which data provider (the layer between the database and EF) do you have?

Comment: Im using **Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework** and **Oracle.ManagedDataAccess**